# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jwplayer

Hi I am using JW player for playing flash videos in my website.video plays in browsers except chrome.I've tried playing in Mozilla and Safari. when I check the console of chrome I get an error message 
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.how do I solve this error

Comment: Please provide a link.

Answer (score 2):

It just means that you're linking something incorrectly. Make sure to check your src and hrefs are valid.

Comment: if it is incorrect how it plays in other browsers ?

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the console?

Comment: well I cant post images with this reputation :(

Comment: could you post some relevant HTML then?

Comment: Lol, of course that's an invalid link you probably meant http://127.0.0.1/videoGallery/foo.flv or file://c:/users/cybro. Can I see your HTML?

Comment: Please give us a link to your site. It will save a lot of time. No one can debug a screenshot.